lapply() eats up memory and doesn't free it until restarting R
I'm reading in large tables of counted sequences into R using lapply() across a list of files. After running a set of lapply() commands to read the files in, I get a lot of memory that does not get released.
flist <- list.files("processed_fastq/bulk/W0/", pattern = "_freq.txt", full.names = TRUE)
W0.bcode.list <- lapply(W0.flist, read.delim, sep = "", header = FALSE)

Here is my Rstudio memory usage report.

While the total size of objects in my environment is:
> pryr::mem_used()
760 MB

Running gc() doesn't resolve this.
Is it generally more efficient to run these kinds of operations in a loop? I'm not an R expert by any means, but I was always told that list operations are more computationally efficient than loops. But when I run lots of lapply(), the session gobbles up memory and it's not possible to free it up until you restart the R session.

Is there any error/problem while running r? Why are you concerned about its memory footprint? The freeing and/or not freeing in high level languages is usually done by the garbage collector. You can call it manually with gc(), but since there is no issue there's no need to do that. It is done automatically.

gc() doesn't clear the used memory for these operations - that's the issue. After running a bunch of chunky lapply operations I can often end up with 30+GB of RAM that's unavailable until you restart R - that's not ideal having 1/3 of my available workstation memory being rendered unavailable. There aren't any errors - this is just what R seems to do and has done as long as I can remember.

Well, in theory (and in practice) an interactive R session is a program workflow from its start to its end. Whatever happens in between may be garbage collected but not necessarily. If you keep the session open you effectively have a program with all its objects at the ready. So if you really are concerned about your program (the session) footprint better end it.

I guess my question is more: I am using list operations because there isn't a defined S3/S4 class for what I am doing, and it's handy to be able to do the same operation on a list of similar data. But since it appears to hog memory, should I be formatting my code differently?

How can you (or anyone reading this) tell whether it's R   or RStudio that is retaining this memory space?

what does base::memory.profile  tell you?

This is not an answer to your question, but for dealing with large text files,, package {vroom} might come in handy. Rather than reading the full data into memory, it indexes the text file(s) and retrieves the data on demand. You can also bulk index all text files in a directory.
